# How to add custom Modules in magento

Tags: magento, module

Hi I want to create a custom Module for Footer which shows the news Headlines.Havent played with custom modules yet.How can i do that.can anyone tell me simple steps to craeate a custom module.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resources you will find are:

- [Module Creator extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1108/modulecreator)
- [Branko's blog post on writing a custom module](http://activecodeline.com/writing-a-custom-module-in-magento-detailed-walktrough)
- [The official Magento wiki article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)

And of course the great [set of articles](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento) written by Stack Overflower [Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) which will help you understand the complex architecture that you are plugging into with your custom module.

Finally, searching Stack Overflow will help a lot!  The Magento forums are full of pretty poor advice, be wary of editing core files and other bad practices...

HTH,
JD

Comment: Hi I tried it It helped in creating the custom module,now as i have got it done one last thing How can I call them on CMS page

Comment: well done, that's a big first step!  Use this syntax to call from a CMS page or static CMS block : {{block type='module/block' template='module/template.phtml'}}, that should work for you.