# Add new in magento

Tags: magento

how to make customize module in magento with fetching value from table ?

Comment: You'll have to get way, way more specific if you want a meaningful answer.  What have you tried?  What issues have you come up against?

Answer (score 1):

Please see this exact same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3726349/336905)

For info, the answer again:

The best resources you will find are:

- [Module Creator extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1108/modulecreator)
- [Branko's blog post on writing a custom module](http://activecodeline.com/writing-a-custom-module-in-magento-detailed-walktrough)
- [The official Magento wiki article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)

And of course the great [set of articles](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento) written by Stack Overflower [Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) which will help you understand the complex architecture that you are plugging into with your custom module.

Finally, searching Stack Overflow will help a lot!  The Magento forums are full of pretty poor advice, be wary of editing core files and other bad practices...

HTH,
JD